# How to make Firefox extension hidden, but downloadable from AMO

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, add-on

Mozilla Add-ons provides an ability to upload your extension to their servers. I need to make it hidden on https://addons.mozilla.org, but be downloadable from my website by direct link to it on https://addons.mozilla.org.

I see that on an add-on page I have a **Hidden** visibility option:

> Hidden: Hosted on https://addons.mozilla.org, but hidden to anyone but authors. Used to temporarily hide listings or discontinue them.

If I will use it, will I have an ability to download this extension directly from Mozilla Add-ons servers?

P.S. I can't switch to it now because I will need to upload a new version of extension for review.

[image: Visibility options]